# Ticking sound from engine bay

Tags: engine, noise, hyundai, elantra

I bought a used 2014 Hyundai Elantra GL (82400kms odo) a week ago and I have been hearing a clicking sound from 1.5 to 2 thousand RPM mark from the engine bay, when I am sitting in the cabin.

Here's a video where I tried to capture the noise.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/yooKrPV8ffxmqEXR8
(Better video available further below)

**UPDATE** : I found a bunch of YouTube videos talking about the same issues, most of them blaming issues with pistons.
Here's one more video with more clearly audible noise : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uRtyPbyomxQ

Is the video's assumption about pistons, correc, tor Could this be something to do with the engine, or timing chain, or any belts, or just lose mounts?

Comment: it sounds like valve ticking,to adjust the valves your engine uses shims it might be best to let the pros do this for you.it might be some thing more serious so i made this a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Sounds a bit like lifter tick. does this car have hydraulic lifter adjustments?

Comment: as far as i know this engine have mecanical lifters https://www.elantraforum.com/forum/4-elantra-sedan-general-discussion/16409-valve-lash-clearance.html and one need shims to adjust them.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to hear, but from what I can make out it sounds like an Intake Manifold leak. They sound like metal on metal ticking, but what you're actually hearing is air getting sucked in through the manifold gasket each time the Pistons compress. The sound gets louder and faster as rpms increase, which is why it's often mistaken for rod knock or a thrown bearing. The intake plenum is made of plastic these days, so I guess they wouldn't be too hard to warp over time. Or if you're lucky it may just be a lose bolt.

Comment: I just added more details to the question, including a youtube video with better sound, showing the exact same noise I am hearing. Maybe that helps? Thought he video deduces that it's got to do with pistons

Comment: Sounds like an Intake manifold leak. Just like the one I repaired on my truck. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ceHLSLJpZy0

Answer (score -1):

It most likely will be a timing chain issue. Either it stretching, or the chain guides are worn down, either way 1500-2000 rpm is idle and the chain isn't under as much tension as it would be under engine load.

You have plastic, metal and metal with plastic surface chain guides, when the plastic is worn out, it allows for a bit of chain slap, much like what most timing chain engines do with a cold start.